# Changing default sign in message

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I want to change message "You need to sign in or sign up before continuing." when I logout from active admin panel. I have changed the message in devise.en.yml but I only want to change for logout.

Comment: Define a new translation variable with custom desired message. Update the logout message with new variable.

Answer (score 1):

When I want to change a flash message from the default I usually set it in the controller

```
# app/admin/devise/sessions.rb 
class ActiveAdmin::Devise::SessionsController

  # POST /resource/sign_in
  def create
    self.resource = warden.authenticate!(auth_options)
    #set_flash_message!(:notice, :signed_in)
    flash[:alert] = 'New message here'
    sign_in(resource_name, resource)
    yield resource if block_given?
    respond_with resource, location: after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
  end
end
```